# Discontinuity on a 3D surface

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I am plotting data of a 3D distribution both with the scatter and the surface plot. As it is possible to see from the following snippets, I am experiencing a discontinuity using the surface plot although the scattered plot doesn't show any missing set of data. Is there a parameter/option I am overlooking at?

The code I am using is the following:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z,
                                   mode='markers',
                                   marker=dict(size=5,
                                               color=d,            # set color to an array/list of desired values
                                               colorscale='Viridis', # choose a colorscale
                                               opacity=1.,
                                               showscale=True          # to show the legend according to the color
                                               )
                                      )])

fig.update_layout(title='TFMeOx MFPADs theory scattered',margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0))
fig.show()
```

[image: ![image|690x403](upload://cChwblCgW8nC1CMguozAmDgexeo.png)]

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=Z, x=X, y=Y, surfacecolor=d_matrix)])
fig.update_layout(title='TFMeOx MFPADs theor surfy', autosize=False,
                #   width=500, height=500,
                #   margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))
                  margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0))
fig.show()
```

[image: surface plot]

Any suggestion is very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you plot a surface from x,y,z you have to tell the plotting software which points form the elementary parts (like a triangle or a quadrilateral) that make up your large surface.

Usually there is something smart im place to guess the elements from a point list or the like . Sometimes you have to pass the shape of the surface array.

But the point is that the algorithm does not know how to handle the last points in the list. It does not know that they are connected to e.g. the first points. It will assume that they are not connected.

There might be a option in your plotting function for this, but usually you just append copies of the first points at the list to the end.

(The [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/surface/) to the function shows a keyword [connectgaps](https://plotly.com/python/reference/surface/#surface-connectgaps), but that might not solve this.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried connectgaps=True, but it is not solving the present issue as you already guessed. How would you proceed? Adding an extra final line, replicating the first one? How this would conserve the same shape of the Z matrix?

Comment: I tried to replicate the problem with a dummy data set here
https://github.com/giammi56/sphere_try.git

Comment: If you use a matrix as surface you probably don't have to append the line but to adjust the correct edges. Not sure how that works, but the approach is the same.